# How can I change these FontAwesome icons that came with my website?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I got a website from HTML5UP to use as my portfolio. I am unable to figure out how to replace these icons that came prebuilt with the website. I don't mind using Font Awesome, I just do not know how to replace them as they aren't relevant.

For example:

```
   <div class="col-4 col-6-medium col-12-small">
            <section class="box style1">
              <span class="icon featured fa-comments"></span>
              <h3>Lean, Six Sigma, Kaizen, Kanban and 5S</h3>
              <p>
                Applicable to both software and industrial settings.
              </p>
            </section>
```

[image: Current icon]

I want to replace that `class="icon featured fa-comments"` with another image. I tried searching FA for one, obtained the HTML for it `<i class="fas fa-industry"></i>` but when I replace it, the formatting isn't the same.

If i change it to `class="icon featured fa-industry"` it doesn't work. Neither does `class="icon featured fas fa-industry"` And if I use `<i class="fas fa-industry"></i>`  the icon is printed without formatting

[image: Icon error]

[image: Icon without formatting]

How can I change just the image? And keep the formatting.

EDIT: Below is a snippet of the main.css file if that helps

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the template you are using has some custom CSS for the  tag or the classes icon and featured. Therefore instead of using

```
<i class="fas fa-industry"></i>
```

Try with

`<span class="icon featured fas fa-industry"></span>`

```css
.icon {
  font-size: 36pt;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />


<div class="col-4 col-6-medium col-12-small">
  <section class="box style1">
    <span class="icon featured fas fa-industry"></span>
    <h3>Lean, Six Sigma, Kaizen, Kanban and 5S</h3>
    <p>
      Applicable to both software and industrial settings.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still did not work. the image still appears as missing... I do not know how to exactly edit only it.

Comment: Okay, maybe let us take a different solution approach. How do I go about changing JUST this icon? Say I will download an icon locally and add it to the images src folder.

How do I go about linking it to the box above?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and I eventually figured it out. For the `fa-industry` icon, use:

```
<span class="icon solid featured fa-industry"></span>
```

If you wanted to use a brand icon, like `fa-python`, use:

```
<span class="icon featured brands fa-python"></span>
```